# SQL Server : return value in specific table2 column based on value in table1

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that gets data from 2 tables.

- `Transaction` table contains week_id, customer_id, upc12,  sales_dollars
- `Products` table contains upc12, column_1, column_2, column_3

I want my query to return the value in products table, based on what the `customer_id` is in the transaction table. `customer_id = 1` should return `column_1`, `customer_id = 2` should return `column_3`, etc.

```
SELECT
    t.week_id, 
    customer_id, 
    upc12, 
    p.___________ sum(t.sales_dollars)
FROM 
    transaction t, products p
WHERE 
    t.upc_12 = p.upc_12
GROUP BY 
    t.week_id, customer_id, upc12, p.___________
```

Sorry if this makes no sense, but my research hasn't been very good, as I don't know how to correctly formulate my question. You probably guessed I'm new to SQL.

Thanks!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: ugh cant format this correctly..is this what you mean:   select... from transaction t JOIN products p ON t.upc12 = p.upc12  ?

Comment: so you want a case statement? e.g. `case customer_id when 1 then col1 when 2 then col3 end`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
;WITH cte as
(
SELECT
    t.week_id, 
    customer_id, 
    upc12, 
    CASE customer_id
        WHEN 1 THEN p.Column_1
        WHEN 2 THEN p.Column_2
        WHEN 3 THEN p.Column_3
    END As ColByCustomer,
    t.sales_dollars
FROM transaction t
INNER JOIN products p on t.upc_12 = p.upc_12
)

SELECT week_id, customer_id, upc12, ColByCustomer, SUM(sales_dollars)
FROM cte
GROUP BY week_id, customer_id, upc12, ColByCustomer
```

Comment: thank you!!  The CASE is exactly what I needed, I did not know that function.  simply amazing!

Comment: Glad to help :-). If an answer solved your problem you should mark it as accepted so that other people will know that the problem is solved.